# Power Query unable to load data from website?

Tags: excel, web-scraping, powerbi, powerquery

I have been using a website to import data into Excel using power query (https://www.verbalcommits.com/transfers/2023/D1) and the web page recently got an update and now it is unable to load in the data. Within power query editor, it gives me the error message of "Expression.Error: Access to the resource is forbidden."

[image]

When I try to refresh the page like I did in the past, I get an error message of "Exception of type 'Microsoft.Mashup.Engine.Interface.ResourceAccessForbiddEnexception' was thrown."

[image]

I have not been able to find a solution elsewhere online, so if anyone is aware on how I can get around this, please help! Thank you.

Comment: Assuming this is powerquery, please go into home ... advanced editor .. and edit your question to paste in the code you are using

Comment: I get the same error. It looks to me like they tightened something up on their end if you used to be able to get to the data. Have you reached out to them to see if they have/offer API access?